# Using SUDO to execute a general command inside a non-accessible directory

Tags: centos, sudo

I  want to grep something inside a directory. But the user dont have permissions in the direcotry. Because of some reasons, i am not allowed to change permissions, group or owner. Just want to know i can access that directory by some entry in the sudoers file.

```
grep -r "some phrase" /path/to/restricted-dir
```

Is there any way to execute the above command using SUDO. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -i
grep -r "some phrase" /path/to/restricted-dir
exit
```

sudo -i puts you in interactive mode, so your prompt turns to '#' and all commands you run are executed as root, until you 'exit'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem, why not just use `sudo`?

```
sudo grep -r "some phrase" /path/to/restricted-dir
```

For example:

```
$ sudo tree -up
.
└── [drwx------ root    ]  foo
    ├── [drwx------ root    ]  bar
    │   └── [drwx------ root    ]  baz
    │       └── [drwx------ root    ]  foobar
    │           └── [-rwx------ root    ]  foo.txt
    └── [-rwx------ root    ]  foo.txt

4 directories, 2 files
```

As you can see above, I have a folder structure with three nested subdirectories of `foo` all of which are owned by root and only root has access to them. Therefore, running normal `grep` fails:

```
$ grep -r foo foo/
grep: foo/: Permission denied
```

Running with `sudo` works perfectly and finds the string `foo` in both files that contain it:

```
$ sudo grep -r foo foo/
foo/bar/baz/foobar/foo.txt:foobar
foo/foo.txt:foobar
```

For more complex commands, you can use either `sudo -i` as suggested by @FrankThomas or `su` if you have the `root` account enabled.